# Remove Joomla metadata from K2 Rss feed

Tags: xml, joomla, rss, feed, joomla-k2

In K2 Rss feed, How to remove Joomla metadatas? I mean :

```
<!-- generator="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" -->
```

and

```
<generator>Joomla! - Open Source Content Management</generator>
```

Here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- generator="Joomla! - Open Source Content Management" -->
<?xml-stylesheet href="/media/system/css/modal.css"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="http://site.com/plugins/system/shortcodes/assets/css/shortcodes.css"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
        <channel>
                <title>Website</title>
                <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
                <link>http://site.com</link>
                <lastBuildDate>Wed, 28 Aug 2013 10:50:56 </lastBuildDate>
                <generator>Joomla! - Open Source Content Management</generator>
                <atom:link rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" href="http://site.com/?format=feed&amp;type=rss"/>
                <language>en-gb</language>
        </channel>
</rss>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply install and enable this plugin: [ByeByeGenerator](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/site-management/seo-a-metadata/12556) (I'm in no way affiliated).

It will remove the generator meta tag anywhere in your site, including the RSS and Atom feeds, and even if you upgrade your Joomla! installation.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you, I had changed generator tag on regular pages by placing `$this->setMetaData('generator','The Company');` but didn't work on RSS urls. The **ByeByeGenerator** is working on both sides. Cheers